# Can you include a Jpeg or any image onto an excel form

Tags: image, excel, jpeg, vba

not sure if this is possible can you add a jpeg or another image to a form created in the vba section in excel? If so would anyone know how to go about doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the  [UserForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264663.aspx)  object, which has a picture property. There's a bit of info  [here](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/pasting_an_image_to_a_userform_control/)  on how to paste an image in a User Form control which you may find helpful. Best of luck!

Comment: Thats brillaint thanks...seems it just doesnt like jpeg files

Comment: @Paula No worries. That's interesting, I'll look into it. No way you can convert the image type in the meantime?

Comment: @Paula also are you using Excel 2011?

Comment: I managed to get to converted to bitmap which it seems to work ok with so that will do the trick :) and I am using excel 2010

Comment: @Paula Great. If you found my answer helpful an upvote is always appreciated!

Comment: sorry I would but it wont let me upvote until I get a 15 reputation..sorry once I get that I will certainly upvote this post